# What's the pythonic way to do a complex initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, initialization

Suppose I have a class `Point`:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Suppose that I always create Points by using a string of the form `x_y`:

```
x, y = my_string.split('_')
p = Point(x, y)
```

Since I always use a string to create a `Point p`. Is it ok to change the `__init__` in this way:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, s):
        x, y = s.split('_')
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Should the `__init__` only take values that will set the attributes or is it ok if it does more than that ?

Comment: That's okay.  A more futureproof version would probably be a `@classmethod` `Point.from_string` that does the splitting and returns a `Point`, but this way isn't wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__` function can take whatever arguments make sense for your application. If your `Point` class is used by others, they might be wondering why they can only instantiate the class by providing a formatted string. You can allow both ways of initialization by using a static method like this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s):
        x, y = s.split('_')
        return cls(x, y)

# example usage
p1 = Point(10, 20)
p2 = Point.from_string("15_25")
```

#### Edit:

As Patrick pointed out in the comments, using a `classmethod` is preferred over using as `staticmethod` as I did initially.

#### Edit 2:

If you're using Python 3.7, you can use a `dataclass` for this:

```
In [1]: from dataclasses import dataclass

In [4]: @dataclass
   ...: class Point:
   ...:     x: int
   ...:     y: int
   ...:     
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def from_string(cls, s):
   ...:         return cls(*s.split("_"))
   ...:

In [5]: Point(1, 2)
Out[5]: Point(x=1, y=2)

In [6]: Point(1, "2")
Out[6]: Point(x=1, y='2')

In [7]: Point.from_string("3_4")
Out[7]: Point(x='3', y='4')
```

But be carful with your types. As the code above shows, there's no automatic type conversion to `int`.

Comment: For "alternate constructors" like this, you generally want to use `classmethod` over `staticmethod` for purposes of subclassing. For example, if there was a `ColoredPoint` subclass that accepted strings like `"1_2_brown"`, you would have to write another `from_string` for that class.  If this was a classmethod that did `return cls(*s.split('_'))`, then that would be taken care of automatically.